# Simulating the annual salary of some lawyers in R

Tags: r, regression, simulation

I'm trying to simulate the annual salary of 30, say, lawyers given their years of experience and age. By design, age and experience are extremely correlated with each other.

I was wondering if my simulation procedure is accurate?

(***Particularly:*** I often see the error term defined as `rnorm(n, 0, some SIGMA)`, but isn't it that we are drawing from a known population and so the the common `SIGMA` should be a single known value.)

**MY ASSUMPTIONS:**

I assumed that both predictors (`age` and `experience`) are highly correlated ($\rho=.99$) normal random variables. As a result, I drew their random realizations from a bivariate normal distribution with some specified `mean` and `sd` for each predictor. Then, I created a linear model assuming the average annual salary of lawyers was `$100000` (`B0`) and that age and experience can each increase the salary by `$6000` (`B1` & `B2`) a year. I then attached the linear model to the mean of the normal distribution of salary and assumed the conditional normals each have a common `sd` of `$700` dollars?

```
library(MASS)
rho = .99 # correlation bet. age & experience
  n = 30  # A sample of 30 lawyers
mnor <- MASS::mvrnorm(n, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1,rho,rho,1), 2)) # bivariate normal draws for 2 predictors
mean.expri = 20 # years
  sd.expri = 5  # years
(expri <- mnor[,1]*sd.expri + mean.expri)
mean.age = 55 # years
  sd.age = 10 # years
(age <- mnor[,2]*sd.age + mean.age)

B0 = 100000 ; B1 = 6000; B2 = 6000 # coefficients' parameters in dollar
sd = 700 # common population sigma for any value of predictors (parameter)
 y = rnorm(n, B0+B1*expri+B2*age, sd)  # Annual Salary
coef(summary(lm(y~ expri + age)))
```

Comment: You didn't give us enough details to tell if it is correct.

Comment: To start, you need to describe your problem in detail. How did you come up with this code? Why did you choose to simulate it like this? What do you know about distributions of the variables you want to simulate? etc.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the details?

Comment: @Tim, Are my assumptions clear?

Comment: It doesn't seem realistic to assume normal distributon of salary ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, but is my simulation technically accurate? Specifically, shouldI use `sd = 700` or `rnorm(n, 0, 700)`? Also, can you please provide a more formal answer?